# using a div contentEditable innerText and innerHTML neither have newlines to and from database

Tags: javascript, string, html, contenteditable

I'm using a div for people to enter text and then I tried saving

```
div.innerText
```

and

```
div.innerHTML
```

to my database but when I bring it back from the database and put it back into the div all of the carriage returns or newlines are gone

innerHTML to database

```
a

b

c

    //in database like this  <div>a</div><div></div><div>b</div><div></div><div>c</div>
```

innerText to database

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
    //how it stored in database  aaaaaa
```

if you could tell me how to handle this situation I would appreciate it greatly thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried to ouput the stored version back to `div.innerText` / `div.innerHTML`?

Comment: Yes and it doesnt have the "returns" newlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div.innerHTML` creates an HTML output of your new lines using `<div>` containers.
Therefore the line breaks will be "replaced".

`div.innerText` uses the "invisible" character `\n` or `\r\n` to mark new lines and it is possible that they are not shown in your database. You can however replace them by `<br>` tags to see if they are there.

```js
document.getElementById("output").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("HTML:");
  console.log(document.getElementById("text").innerHTML);
  console.log("Text:");
  var text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
  console.log(text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'));
});
```

```css
#text {
  background-color:#FAFAFA;
  border: red solid 1px;
  height:150px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="output">
  Show in console
</button>

<div id="text" contenteditable>

</div>
```

`console.log(text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'));` replaces all different kinds of possible new lines into `<br>` tags.

Comment: ahhhh, this is what I was looking for, 1 more thing chrome puts the <br> in there but Microsoft edge doesn't, and also when I hit return twice in Microsoft edge and use the text.replace it only puts one newline in there

Comment: I don't have Edge on my machine, but I just saw that IE 11 uses `<p>` tags instead of `<div>` in case that would change something for you.  Well... Microsoft's browsers probably will always work different from all the other browsers...

Comment: This is how IE 11 renders the `.innerHTML` : `<p>sdf</p><p><br></p><p>sdf</p>`. It creates a `<p>`tag for every new line and puts a `<br>` tag if into it if `<p>` is empty, otherwise it places the text into it.

Comment: just one more question, do you think storing innerHTML or innerText in the database is a better idea, because I'm building like a social networking site, I think I want to store innerHTML because it has everything in it already?

Comment: Depends on what you store. If you build something similar to Facebook I would say: store the text and the URL (if set) separately and load the URL box only when the user sees the post. So you need to store less data in your database. If you need to show complex code and it would need a lot of time to generate it client side, then store it in your database.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, this is the answer I was looking for, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute `<textarea>` element for `<div>` with `contenteditable` attribute set. Encode, decode `.value` of `textarea` using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), `decodeURIComponent()` or format data as `JSON` utilizing [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), `JSON.parse()`

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button")
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
button.onclick = function() {
  var value = textarea.value
  console.log(encodeURIComponent(value)
             , decodeURIComponent(value)
             , JSON.stringify(value)
             , JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
             );
}
```

```css
textarea {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

You can use
```

```html
<button>click</button><br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: I was using a textarea before but I want to use a div so I can recognize links and pictures

Comment: You can parse the `.value` of `textarea` element for well-formed `<a>` and `<img>` `html` strings. What should be done when `<a>`, `<img>` `html` strings are parsed?